# Codeigniter - form validation not passed but no error message shown

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm using codeigniter for a login form validation. The code was previously working fine, but when I made some modifications, it just do not work now.

When I try to type in wrong or leave blank for password or username, the error message is shown as normal, but when I type in the correct username and password, `$this->form_validation->run()` just give me `FALSE` with an empty `validation_errors()` string.

I've tried to restore my old working controller php, but this error resists.

Full code related is available at

- User Controller http://pastebin.com/nt2SDVnv
- Login View http://pastebin.com/9hEc0EJB
- User Model http://pastebin.com/p1z0zLM8

Only related code are pasted below:

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
    }
    function login(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_username_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|md5|callback_password_check');
        $this->_username = $this->input->post('username');                //用户名


        $remember_me = $this->input->post('remember_me');
        $json_string = $this->input->cookie('userinfo');
        $userinfo_json = json_decode($json_string);

        if(isset($userinfo_json->username)){
            if ($this->username_check($userinfo_json->username)){
                $this->user_model->login($userinfo);
                redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }
        }


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $this->load->view('account/login');
        } else {
            $userinfo=$this->user_model->get_by_username($this->_username);
            $this->user_model->login($userinfo);
            if($remember_me=="on"){$this->user_model->write_session($userinfo);}
            redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }


    }
    function username_check($username){
        if ($this->user_model->get_by_username($username)){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'User name not exist.');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    function password_check($password) {
        $password = md5($password);
        if ($this->user_model->password_check($this->_username, $password)){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('password_check', 'Incorrect username or paswsword.');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login - <?=$this->admin_model->get_title();?></title>
    <?php $this->load->view('gy/head');?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $this->load->view('gy/header');?>
    <div class="hero-unit header">
        <div class="container">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <h1>Sign in</h1>    
                <p class="lead">Log into <?=$this->admin_model->get_title();?>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="span5 offset3">
        <?php if(validation_errors() !== '' || @(!$err_message == '')){ ?>
        <div class="alert alert-error fade in">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <strong>Error!</strong> <?=validation_errors('<span>','</span>');?> <?=@$err_message?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if(@$message!=''){ ?>
        <div class="alert fade in alert-success">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <strong>Success!</strong> <?=$message?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
            <?php echo form_open('login',array('class'=>'form-horizontal')); ?>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="username">User name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label for="remember_me" class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="remember_me"> Remember me (30 days)
                </label>
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
        </Form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php $this->load->view('gy/footer');?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Model:**

```
<?php 
class user_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('session');

  }
     function login($userinfo)
     {
         $data = array('username'=>$userinfo->username,
                       'user_id'=>$userinfo->id, 
                       'role'=>$userinfo->role,
                       'logged_in'=>TRUE);
         $this->session->set_userdata($data);
     }
     function write_session($userinfo)
     {
        $user_json = json_encode($userinfo);
        $cookie = array(
            'name'   => 'userinfo',
            'value'  => $user_json,
            'expire' => '2592000',
            'secure' => TRUE
        );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
     }
     function get_by_username($username)
     {
         $this->db->where('username', $username);
         $query = $this->db->get('users');
         if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
         {
             return $query->row();
         }
         else
         {
             return FALSE;
         }
     }
     function password_check($username, $password)
     {                
         if($user = $this->get_by_username($username))
         {
             return $user->password == $password ? TRUE : FALSE;
         }
         return FALSE;
     }
}
```

Comment: Any native PHP function that accepts one parameter can be used as a rule, like htmlspecialchars, trim, MD5, etc. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#preppingdata @fabiano-araujo

Comment: Totally ashamed, I'll return to my cave and hibernate until next season. Sorry for that.

Comment: Still don't get it, where's the error? I'm currently having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the trim rule. It doesn't return a Boolean and I suppose you haven't set any error message for that rule. trim() should be run on the username and password, after the validation runs successful. If you just wanna check if the input has blank spaces You could add a rule to check with the strpos() but again in a custom callback. Just remember to use the Identical opperator '===' instead of the equal '==' .

**Controller :**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','callback_space_check|required|xss_clean|callback_username_check');

function space_check($input){
   if(strpos(' ',$input)===false){
       return TRUE;
    }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('space_check', '%s contains space.');
            return FALSE;
        }
}
```